# Correct way to run artisan commands in docker-compose automatically

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a Laravel project image(for local using at first) with the docker-compose. So, I made the following files:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 8020:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/swdocker
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/swdocker
      - ./storage/app/public:/var/www/public/storage
    #entrypoint: sh -c 'sleep 30 && php artisan migrate'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**Dockerfile** for nginx:

```
FROM nginx
ADD docker/nginx/conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d
WORKDIR /var/www/swdocker
```

**Dockerfile** for php:

```
FROM php:8-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql


COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

USER 1000

WORKDIR /var/www/swdocker
```

And the tuned **default.conf** file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/swdocker/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

If I up the containers without migrations(they are commented) I need to run migrations manually(with docker-compose exec from terminal). And it works. Is it the best practice? I would like to up the project running only once docker image. I need to run artisan queue and scheduler for my project as well.

I tried to run migrations as entrypoint, but unsuccessfully. In this case I see my php container exits after migrations. I cannot understand how to solve this problem. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

what I normally do is to put all the commands I want to run in a bash script file, and execute  this file .this also helped me when I wanted to create a basic CI/CD pipeline

```
docker-compose down --remove-orphans
docker-compose build //in case I changed docker-compose file
docker-compose up -d

docker exec {container-name} bash -c "composer update"
docker exec {container-name} bash -c "php artisan migrate"
```

as for the scheduler`php artisan schedule run`,the most straight forward way I found was to add

```
docker exec {container-name} bash -c "php artisan schedule:run" >> /home/{user}/output.txt
```

where `output.txt` is just a file that will show you the output of the command.

Hope this would be of any help to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this way. I mean using shell script. But when I try to up my project I can see some problems with DB. I think there is something wrong with user permissions:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel1 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Comment: `docker-compose up --build -d  
docker exec php bash -c "php artisan migrate"  
docker exec php bash -c "php artisan queue:work"`  
Migrations don't run

Comment: Thanks so very much. After a day of trying I can finally move on to coding.